# Why Does the Content Within This Div Screw Up the Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css

You can see this here...

http://jsfiddle.net/cf9Hu/

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="outer">
            <div>
               Blah
                <br />
               Blah
            </div>
            <div class="inner">
                x
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="outer">
            <div>Blah</div>
            <div class="inner">
                x
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="outer">
            <div>Blah</div>
            <div class="inner">
                x
            </div>
        </div>     
    </div>
```

and here is my css...

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border:solid 1px black;
}

.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to fix it, use vertical-align.

```
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Or, you can use "inline-table" for display to get the same result

```
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-table;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Vertical-align is the property you were missing @ek_ny. Position relative however is not necessary.

Comment: He needs "position: relative;" for his "inner" div, which uses absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can Either give vertical alignment to you Outer Div

```
"vertical-align: top; OR  vertical-align: bottom;"

.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Or you can change the "display:inline-block;" to `"float:left;"`

```
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Hope this helps!